# TFS vNext TestRunner ignore double dlls

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, mstest

In our solution we have about 60 projects. There are some core-"ish" libraries which are referenced by other projects. Our unit-tests are put in the same dlls as the production code (no specific unit test projects).

My problem starts with the continious integration build when using the Visual Studio Test Runner in our Team Foundation Server.
I want the test runner to automatically run all tests in the created dlls. Because of conenvience reasons I don't want to manually add paths to the created dlls.

Currently I'm using a wildcard like this (all our dlls start with Company.*):

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\**\bin\x64\Release\Company.*.dll
```

In this way all dlls are found, but they are found more than one time, as the dlls get copied to the output dir of the referencing dll.
This yields in a lot of time which is wasted with running the same unit test multiple times (>20).

So what am I looking for:

1. Best would be something to tell vstest.console.exe to include dlls
   that already run (I checked the command line options - nothing).
2. Another option would be a special wild-card for the mini-match-template of the TFS so that no double dlls are passed to the vstest.console.exe (I don't know of anything and google neither).
3. Another best practice how you guys handle your unit tests so that they are automatically run on continious integration.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a common and recommend project structure. We usually use NuGet to manage dlls in TFS source control instead of project referenced. Also create a separate test project to handle unit test.

For the workflows, please take a look at this MSDN blog: [Testing in Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment Workflows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/testing-in-continuous-integration-and-continuous-deployment-workflows/)

In your case, you may have to specify the corresponding dlls path for test. You could also add a task to copy these dlls to another folder  and then use *.wildcard for all test dlls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I don't really understand, what exactly are you referring to with nuget-packages here.
We decided internally to put our tests into our production assemblies, as this creates less assemblies and the tests always stay close to the production code. Also not all members have to be public.

We will evaluate the copy approach you mentioned.